# Why does the variable executes the window object right away and not store it instead?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-scope

I would like to understand what's happening with the code in which a variable is not stored immediately, but instead executed first before it can be called. An example code can be this (in the global scope):

```
var alertMe = alert("I\'m being executed then stored to be called again, but why?");
```

Comment: Yes, the function executes first, otherwise it can't return anything to the variable, and in this case the `alert()` function returns `undefined` as it has no return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are storing the result of calling the function, not storing a function.

This would be what you are after:

```
var alertMe = function () { 
        alert("I\'m being executed then stored to be called again, but why?"); 
    };
```

And then when you want to call it:

```
alertMe();
```